# How can I check the class is clicked or not by using If () javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 type of class like: A-1, A-2, A-3, B-1, B-2, B-3... and I want to check if I click class A-1 then class B-1 will show up. Can I catch event click() if click() = true in Js?

I've tried with for loop and if to check inside but it's won't work.
All answers are very appreciated. Thank you!

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if($(".A-" + i).click()) {  
    $(".B-" + i).toggle();                                  
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the intent behind looping 10x? You need to learn about event handlers. If you attach a listener on the click event for the elements you are clicking then you can do your toggle in the handler. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***To quick fix your code:-***

```
$("[class^=A-]").on("click",function(){
  $(".B-"+($(this).index() +1)).toggle();
})
```

Working snippet:-https://jsfiddle.net/ktmLhzv7/

***But a better approach*** is instead of `A-1,A-2,....` and `B-1,B-2,....` add 2 classes `A-kind`,`B-kind` to distinguish your elements, and then simply do:-

```
$('.A-kind').click(function(){
  $('.B-kind :eq('+$(this).index()+')').toggle();
});
```

Working snippet:-https://jsfiddle.net/a2qL5zkb/

Note:- it's  a sample example, elements can be different, but if you have same classes then code will work for-sure.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```js
$("[id^=A-]").on("click",function(){
console.log($(this).attr('id'));
var last = $(this).attr('id').match(/(\d+)/)[1];
$("#B-"+last).toggle();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the actions you want inside the event listener:

```js
let allArray = document.querySelectorAll(".clickable");

allArray.forEach(function(allEl) {      
    allEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if(!this.classList.contains("on")){
            allArray.forEach(function(allElCl){
                allElCl.classList.remove("on");
            });
            let onArray = document.querySelectorAll("[data-id='" + this.dataset.id + "']");
            onArray.forEach(function(onEl){
                onEl.classList.toggle("on");
            });
        }else{
            allArray.forEach(function(allElCl){
                allElCl.classList.remove("on");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.a > div{
    background: dodgerblue;
}

.b > div{
    background: green;
}

.clickable{
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 1em;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.clickable.on{
  background: orangered;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <div class="A-1 clickable" data-id="1">A-1</div>
    <div class="A-2 clickable" data-id="2">A-2</div>
    <div class="A-3 clickable" data-id="3">A-3</div>
</div>
<div class="b">
    <div class="B-1 clickable" data-id="1">B-1</div>
    <div class="B-2 clickable" data-id="2">B-2</div>
    <div class="B-3 clickable" data-id="3">B-3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having equal number of triggers (`A-*`) and targets (`B-*`) is simple if you use jQuery.

- No need to use consecutively numbered classes -- a single class for all triggers and another for targets will suffice.

  ```
  <a href='#/' class='A'>A-1</a1> ... <section class='B'>B-1</section>
  ```
- Delegate the click event to all triggers

  ```
  $('.A').on('click', function() {...
  ```
- Determine the index number of the clicked trigger in relation to its sibling triggers

  ```
  var idx = $(this).index();
  ```
- Toggle the target at the same index number in relation to its sibling targets

  ```
  $('.B').eq(idx).toggle();
  ```

See [**.index()**](https://api.jquery.com/index/) and [**.eq()**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) for more details.

---

**Demo 1** is the jQuery that was described above and **Demo 2** is the plain JavaScript version.

#### Demo 1 - jQuery

```js
$('.A').on('click', function() {
  var idx = $(this).index();
  $('.B').eq(idx).toggle();
});
```

```css
:root {
  font: 400 3vw/1.2 Consolas
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1vh 1vw;
}

section {
  display: none;
  border: 3px inset grey;
  height: 10vh
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href='#/' class='A'>A-1</a>
  <a href='#/' class='A'>A-2</a>
  <a href='#/' class='A'>A-3</a>
  <a href='#/' class='A'>A-4</a>
  <a href='#/' class='A'>A-5</a>
</nav>
<article>
  <section class='B'>B-1</section>
  <section class='B'>B-2</section>
  <section class='B'>B-3</section>
  <section class='B'>B-4</section>
  <section class='B'>B-5</section>
</article>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

#### Demo 2 - JavaScript

**Details commented in demo**

```js
// Register parent of triggers to click event
document.querySelector('nav').onclick = toggleSection;

/** toggleSection(e)
@param: event [Event Object]
//A - event.target always point to the tag user clicked
//B - Collect all .A into a NodeList
//C - Collect all .B into a NodeList
//D - Find .indexOf() of clicked link in relation to it sibling
      links and convert NodeList of links into an array:[...links]
//E - If clicked has class .A...
//F - Get the section tag at the index derived from line D and
      toggle the .active class assignment to it
//G - If clicked tag doesn't have class .A then terminate function
*/
function toggleSection(event) {
  const clicked = event.target; //A
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('.A'); //B
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.B'); //C
  const index = [...links].indexOf(clicked); //D

  if (clicked.matches('.A')) { //E
    sections[index].classList.toggle('active'); //F
  }
  return false; //G
}
```

```css
:root {
  font: 400 3vw/1.2 Consolas
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1vh 1vw;
}

section {
  display: none;
  border: 3px inset grey;
  height: 10vh
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href='#/' class='A'>A-1</a>
  <a href='#/' class='A'>A-2</a>
  <a href='#/' class='A'>A-3</a>
  <a href='#/' class='A'>A-4</a>
  <a href='#/' class='A'>A-5</a>
</nav>
<article>
  <section class='B'>B-1</section>
  <section class='B'>B-2</section>
  <section class='B'>B-3</section>
  <section class='B'>B-4</section>
  <section class='B'>B-5</section>
</article>
```